# Can MahApps.Metro be used in a Windows Form Application?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-metro

Im using the MahApps.Metro on http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/ with Visual Studio 2012.
In the documentation, they explain how to implement it on WPF, I was wondering can it be used in windows form applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use it in Windows forms application as [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) is built on top of WPF stack.

But you can use/embed MahApps.Metro [controls](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#controls) inside win forms application by hosting it inside [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control.

Comment: Perfect, can you give me an example on how I can do this?

Comment: Knowing that I have a very large WF application, would you recommend that I go through the trouble of transforming my application into WPF? Does it have other advantages other than design? Or should I stick to the solution you gave me?

Comment: If I was you, I would use any API that works on WinForms and give look and feel of Metro style apps. Example - http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/metro-ui-controls.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, however Im looking for something free, I would follow your advice if I could find anything free. If you don't know any free API's would you recommend transforming to WPF? Or should I use the first method you told me about?